# spark `reduceGroups` error overloaded method with alternatives

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Running the spark-shell with Spark version 2.0.1 and Scala version 2.11.8.

The following code fails to type check:

```
val is = sc.parallelize(0 until 100)
val ds = is.map{i => (s"${i%10}", i)}
val gs = ds.groupByKey(r => r._1)
gs.reduceGroups((v: ((String, Int), (String, Int))) => (v._1._1, v._1._2 + v._2._2))
```

The error message is

```
<console>:32: error: overloaded method value reduceGroups with alternatives:
  (f: org.apache.spark.api.java.function.ReduceFunction[(String, Int)])org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[(String, (String, Int))] <and>
  (f: ((String, Int), (String, Int)) => (String, Int))org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[(String, (String, Int))]
 cannot be applied to ((((String, Int), (String, Int))) => (String, Int))
       gs.reduceGroups((r : ((String, Int), (String, Int))) => (r._1._1, r._1._2 + r._2._2))
```

As far as I can tell, the lambda I pass to `reduceGroups` exactly matches the signature required by the second alternative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`reduceGroups` expects a function which takes two arguments, while function you pass is a functions of a single argument. Comparing signatures you pass:

```
((V, V)) ⇒ V
```

while expected is:

```
(V, V) ⇒ V
```

where `V` is `(String, Int)`.

You can use:

```
gs.reduceGroups(
  (v1: (String, Int), v2: (String, Int)) => (v1._1, v1._2 + v2._2)
)
```

A more concise solution, which doesn't duplicate the keys:

```
spark.range(0, 100)
  .groupByKey(i => s"${i % 10}")
  .reduceGroups(_ + _)
```